# all of my php syntax is true,but update query is not working in while loop

Tags: php

This is cancel_order function,that also in it will call the `increase_gameamount()` function, i am trying to call `increament_gameamount()` function it works but when I try to call it from while loop nothing changes in database.

```
//cancel function
function cancel_order($ord) {   
  global $conn;
  $bqty = 0;
  $gqty = 0;
  $res = array();
  echo "entered cancel function " . $ord . "<br>";
  $st = "select (B_qty+G_qty) newqt, B_GM_ID from tb_basket b, tb_game g
    where b.B_GM_ID = g.G_ID
    and B_O_ID='$ord' "; 
  $sql = $conn->prepare($st); 
  $sql->execute(); 
  $sql->bind_result($newqt, $gid);
  $i = 0;
  while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $res[$i][0] = $newqt;
    $res[$i][1] = $gid;
    $i++;
  }
  $j = 0;
  $sql->free_result();
  $sql->close();
  while($j < sizeof($res)) {
    echo $gd = $res[$j][0] . "<br>";
    echo $qty = $res[$j][1] . "<br>";
    increament_gameamount($gd, $qty);
    $j++;
  }
}

//increament function
function increament_gameamount($gameid, $new_qty) {
  global $conn;
  echo "entered increament_gameamount function";
  echo $gameid;
  echo $new_qty;
  $varupdateqty = $conn->prepare("update tb_game set G_qty=? where  G_ID=?");           
  $varupdateqty->bind_param("ss", $new_qty, $gameid);
  $varupdateqty->execute();
  echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: You are not binding a second variable to your query in `increament_gameamount`

Comment: can you tell me the right syntax

Comment: but i am calling increament_gameamount function from another php page,it works without errors,it means that the problem is not in the function it seems to me,please tell me the right syntax and thank you

Comment: @JamesPaterson Not sure if the question has been edited since you posted your comment, but it looks to me like the OP is binding 2 parameters.

Comment: i am waiting any response

Comment: My guess you are not matching ID because `<br>' is being concatenated on to it. Or the type of the column for new_qty is int and you are passing a string.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments I think you are failing on the `WHERE` of your query because

```
echo $gd=$res[$j][0]."<br>";
```

is making $gd a string like `125<br>` and the DB cannot find that.

Also, this would cause an error but if the type of your column is int and you pass:

```
echo $qty=$res[$j][1]."<br>";
```

again you make $qty something like `1000<br>` and that would fail again this would be an error the above for ID check would not.

**UPDATE**

Just realized I did not specifially state the resolution. Set the variables then echo them and you should be all good.

```
$gd=$res[$j][0];
$qty=$res[$j][1];

echo $gd . "<br>" . $qty . "<br>";
```